# Use getDeclaredConstructor() with Class parameter

Tags: java, constructor

Given is a class `A`. The constructor of the class `A` takes a single class `B` as argument, i.e.:

```
A(B.class)
```

Is it possible to get this constructor of `A` via the [`A.class.getDeclaredConstructor(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29) method and how does the call look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would just be this:

```
A.class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.class)
```

Live example: http://ideone.com/UNzU4J.

(Remember that generic type information is discarded before run-time, so `Class<B>` is the same as `Class`.)